# DIV centered vertically, relative to window. Scrollable Horizontally. Next to fixed div

Tags: html, css

Here's an Illustration of what I need.

[image]

On the left a fixed div and on the right a horizontally scrolling div that is something like 12000px. I need the right div to center vertically in the window when it is re-sized. I can't get the usual tags I use (position:relative and margin:auto) to work on this. I assume it's because the div overflows on the sides of the screen?

Answer (score 2):

This interface should accomplish what your mockup shows. Thanks.

http://jsfiddle.net/9tV4y/2/

Comment: You're very welcome. Is that working for you? Need any adjustments?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not at all good at laying out pages, but this CSS is what you want for the left, horizontally scrolled, `div`,

```
.horizontal_scroll{
    float:left;
    overflow:auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width : 500px;
    height : 500px;
}
```

and applied to the `div`,

```
 <div class="horizontal_scroll"> ... </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Both the width and height are percentage-based (although you can change either to any other type of length that you would like). If you change the `width` of the left column, be sure to change the `left` of the right column to be the same. The vertical positioning is done with the `top:0;bottom:0;margin:auto 0;height:70%;`. Positioning, top/bottom margin, and height must all be set in order for it to work.

Here's the [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uAC7A/).

## HTML

```
<div id="lc"></div>
<div id="rc">Here's some text that does not wrap. This would be replaced with images, of course.</div>
```

## CSS

```
<style>
html, body {height:100%;}
#lc {position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px; width:20%; height:100%; background:lime;}
#rc {background:red; height:75%; position:fixed; left:20%;right:0;top:0; bottom:0;margin:auto 0;overflow-x:auto;overflow-y:hidden;white-space:nowrap;}
</style>
```

***Note:** Be sure to set the `height` of all elements from `html` to `#lc`/`#rc`'s parent nodes to `100%`.*